# Dynamically route to Flask actions based on URL

Tags: python, flask

Want a quick and dirty Flask test server where I can type in a url path

```
0.0.0.0/**something**
```

and get it to call a corresponding method of the same name.

Something like this:

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/<action>')
def do_it(action=None):

    if {PSEUDO: The method exists, call it}
    else:
        return 'Action not found'

def something():

    return 'Did something'

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

Does Flask have a mechanism to help with this or do I have to get messy with reflection?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure how messy that is, but it seems pretty straight forward:

```
  try:                                                                        
      return globals()[action]()                                              
  except KeyError:                                                           
      return 'Action not found'
```

Answer (score 4):

It is a really bad idea to allow the client to run arbitrary code on your server. Instead, consider putting all the available actions in a class, and restricting the choice to the methods of the class:

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)

class Actions:
    def something(self):
        return 'Did something'

    def something_else(self):
        return 'Did something else'

my_actions = Actions()

@app.route('/<action>')
def do_it(action = None):
    op = getattr(my_actions, action, None)
    if callable(op):
        return op()
    else:
        return 'Action not found'

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug = True)
```

Comment: @Miguel- Thanks, yeah i know it's bad- just needed something Q&D but yours is def the smarter way